# C# Parsing Block of Text

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, text

One of the functions in the API I am using is returning basically just a large block of text, seperating each key/value by a semi-colon. How would I parse text like this in C#?

> result=success;income_today=;income_thismonth=;income_thisyear=;orders_pending=19;orders_today_cancelled=0;orders_today_pending=0;orders_today_fraud=0;orders_today_active=0;orders_today_total=0;orders_yesterday_cancelled=0;orders_yesterday_pending=3;orders_yesterday_fraud=2;orders_yesterday_active=0;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, that looks like a case of:

- Call `text.Split(';')` to split the block into key-value pairs
- Call `pair.Split('=')` on each pair to split it into key and value

Note that [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx) has various overloads you may want to look at for options around the number of strings to return, whether to suppress empty values etc.

Comment: haha thanks :P Also, is this about right? http://www.ampaste.net/d5fb70b78 When I do listBox1.Items.Add(stat); it prints out the key/value fine, but when I do listBox1.Items.Add(values); it adds a ton of "String[] Array" to the listbox.

Comment: @Brett: Yes, it would - that's what you get when you call ToString on an array :) You could try `AddRange(stats)` instead...

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem recently. Here is a piece of code that might be useful for you. The strategy is the same as in [Jon Skeet's anwers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712586/c-parsing-block-of-text/4712605#4712605) .

It looks like the keys are unique in your block of text, hence you may use `Dictionary`

```
string[] pairs = block.Split(';');
Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var element in pairs)
{
    var tmp = element.Split('=');
    var key = tmp[0];
    var val = tmp.Length == 2 ? tmp[1] : string.Empty;
    values.Add(key,val );   
}

foreach (var el in values)
{
    Console.WriteLine(el);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And here's the one-liner (formatted over multiple lines for clarity).

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = raw
    .Split(new [] { ';', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => x.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [String.Split(Char[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx).  Adapting the example you would need `string [] split = words.Split(new Char [] {';'});`

Comment: Note that you don't need to explciitly write the "new char[] { }" part as the parameter is a parameter array (params).

Comment: Ah I see so if the array is only one element string [] split = words.Split(';'); will suffice?